# No rule to make target in Maefile

Tags: unix, makefile, gnu-make

I'm learning to write makefiles. I made my own simple one just to try and test, but every time I run make, i get:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/%.cpp', needed by `obj'.  Stop.
```

I googled. I'm pretty sure I typed everything correctly, and my folders are set up the way they should be. Here is the makefile:

```
CC = g++
LD = g++

NAME = app
OBJ_DIR = obj 
SRC_DIR = src 

CC_FLAGS = -std=c++0x

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o
    $(LD) $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $< -o $@ $(CC_FLAGS)

clean:
    rm $(NAME) $(OBJ_DIR) -rf
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
$(NAME): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o
```

is not correct.  This is not a pattern rule (because the target doesn't contain a pattern character, `%`) and so it's interpreted as an explicit rule, saying that `app` depends on the actual file named `obj/%.o` which doesn't exist, and make doesn't know how to build it (because there's no file `src/%.cpp`).

You need to change this to:

```
$(NAME): $(OBJ_DIR)/foo.o ...
```

or whatever object files you have.

Comment: Yes, that is it. Thank you. I'm now not able to compile because it ignores my c++0x flag, but well, that is another question I guess.